# Problem in hosting Angular SSR app to Vercel

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, vercel

I was upgrading my old Angular SSR app to v17 and hosting it on Vercel. The problem is:
On this URL https://space-x-upgrade.vercel.app/launchList , the page appears hydrated from the server- there is no api call for JSON in Network tab and view source shows complete markup, but https://space-x-upgrade.vercel.app doesn't behave in the same way. I have only 1 component in the app i.e. launchList.
Can someone guide me towards correct Route setup to resolve this issue. I have tried adding and removing redirectTo, didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

So as I was expecting, the problem was in my Vercel configuration.
After hours and hours of trial and error, I decided to change the framework to 'None':
[image: Build Configuration]

Then in order to override the Vercel commands, I specified the devCommand in vercel.json:

[image: vercel.json]

After deployment when I hit the default route, it was rendered on the server. Documenting the fix here for anyone facing similar issues.

New App Url: https://space-x-liart.vercel.app

Comment: please consider to add more in depth, this solution simply useless I have tried and it didn't work

Comment: @SefatAnam: What is the problem you are facing? I will frame my answer according to that.

Comment: I want pretty straight forward deployment in vercel with zero configuration. Good thing is I achieved this already. In your solution where should I create api/index.js file is confusing or should I add this into tsconfig file or not those things are not clear.

Comment: @SefatAnam: Got it. But now I would like to know how you hosted SSR app on Vercel without any configuration. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I suggest you create a SSR app in version 17 & then direct host with the default configuration in vercel, you will get the answers. Hint: There are some magic in angular.json @RishabhShukla

Comment: thank you @SefatAnam. I will try this. I believe I am having to do all these extra configurations because I am coming from an Angular 14 app which I upgraded to v17. Need to port everything on  a new v17 App and check.

Comment: compare the build part of `angular.json` of v17 and update accordingly if you upgrade from v14, I believe after that `ng serve` will serve SSR rendering default on port 4200  and good to go in vercel @Rishabh Shukla